# Bind width of RichTextBox to grid in Template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, richtextbox, bin

I have following Theme-Template for `ListViewItems` but the `RichTextBox` inside shows the text vertically.
How can i edit the `RichTextBox` so the text is shown horizontally?

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="InformationListItemTheme">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <RichTextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="275"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="JA"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="SCH"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="ELT"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="KIN"/>
                        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="SON"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding JA}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SCH}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ELT}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding KIN}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding SON}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: When I try your code, the `RichTextBox` is always sized to the width of the column.

Comment: Also, please provide a propper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help others to understand your problem faster and makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: @Felix the RichTextBox is sized to the width of the column but the text in RichTextBox is shown vertically instead of horizontally. Any ideas for this problem?

Comment: @stutski: Can you try to replace your `RichTextBox` by `<RichTextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="275"><FlowDocument MinPageWidth="40"/></RichTextBox>` or `<RichTextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="275" MinWidth="40"/>`, only for the test?

Comment: @Jackdaw i tried both but theRichTextBox has a width of 40 then and doesent get bigger with the grid.

Comment: @stutski: Consider to post a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: @Jackdaw i posted a reproducible example. Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for the extended example. (For the next time:  this is supposed to be eddited into your original question rather than putting it into an answer.)
Unfortunately, your example is far from **minimal**. Is the problem only reproducible when using a template or can you just use a plain grid? Also, the whole inner grid (containing "JA", "SCH",...) can most likely be left out as it has nothing to do with the problem itself. Also, there is no content in the RichTextBox. So when I try your code, there is not text displayed. Neither vertically nor horizontally.

Comment: Sorry for the circumstances. The problem is only reproducible when im using the RichTextBox in a template. When i put the RichTextBox on a plain grid the widht adjust to the grid column. The RichTextBox should not have any content, it is only for user input. Even without text in the RichTextBox the width should adjust to the column width, right? As said, when im using the RichTextBox in a plain grid the RichTextBox fill the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

i made a reproducible example.

**User-Control with ListView and the template for the ListViewItems:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Protocol.MVVM.View.TestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Protocol.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:usc="clr-namespace:Protocol.UserControls" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Protocol.MVVM.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="500">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:InformationsViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Information"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                   FontSize="34"
                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Name"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   FontSize="12"
                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Information"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   FontSize="12"
                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Docomentation"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   FontSize="12"
                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Informations}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ListViewInformation"
                      Margin="2"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      Background="Transparent"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="false">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="4" MinHeight="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                            <RichTextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="275" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            </RichTextBox>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="JUG" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="SCH" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="ELT" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="KIN" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="SON" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Jug}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                </TextBox>

                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Sch}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                </TextBox>

                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Elt}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                </TextBox>

                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Kin}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                </TextBox>

                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Son}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                </TextBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
internal class InformationsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<InformationsItem> informations = new ObservableCollection<InformationsItem>();


    public InformationsViewModel()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            Informations.Add(new InformationsItem("Name", "Information", "Jug", "Sch", "Elt", "Kin", "Son"));
        }

    }



    public ObservableCollection<InformationsItem> Informations
    {
        get { return informations; }
        set
        {
            informations = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Informations");
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
internal class InformationsItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string name;
    string information;
    string jug;
    string sch;
    string elt;
    string kin;
    string son;

    public InformationsItem(string name, string information = "", string jug = "", string sch = "", string elt = "", string kin = "", string son = "")
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.information = information;
        this.jug = jug;
        this.sch = sch;
        this.elt = elt;
        this.kin = kin;
        this.son = son;

    }


    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    public string Information
    {
        get { return information; }
        set
        {
            information = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Information"));
        }
    }

    public string Jug
    {
        get { return jug; }
        set
        {
            jug = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Jug"));
        }
    }

    public string Sch
    {
        get { return sch; }
        set
        {
            sch = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Sch"));
        }
    }
    public string Elt
    {
        get { return elt; }
        set
        {
            elt = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Elt"));
        }
    }

    public string Kin
    {
        get { return kin; }
        set
        {
            kin = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Kin"));
        }
    }

    public string Son
    {
        get { return son; }
        set
        {
            son = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Son"));
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see in this example, the RichTextBox doesnt take the whole width of the variable column. The RichTextBox is stays small but should be as large as the column.
What is here the problem? Should i bind the widht of the RichTextBox to something?

Thank you and best regards